# Localization for footer

Tags: support, localization, footer, russian-stackoverflow

Recently, a new footer has been rolled out for all Stack Exchange sites. For localized sites like Stack Overflow in ... Russian, Portuguese, Spanish, Japanese, there are a few footer items that are partially available for translation. e.g. in ruSO:

> [image: footer]

Should the other items (marked by free-hand red circles) be available for translation too?

Answer (score -2):

If someone isn't able to understand the name of the site in English, they they aren't going to be able to meaningful contribute (or learn from) the site, because it's content is all going to be in English.  Localizing the site names is only going to give the false impression to someone looking at those links in the footer that the localized language is going to be appropriate on that site.

Comment: Agreed that site names should no be translated if all their content present in English. But my question is mostly about site categories (right FHRC). Moreover already translated links such as "Legal", "About", "Press" etc refer to English-only pages, but they all avalable for translate already.